# htaccess issue causing styles and images not to load

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For some reason stylesheets and images are not loading on my site :(

Don't really know why I believe it may be to do with my  htaccess file here is how it currently is.

## UPDATE - NEW FILE

```
#SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /public/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine on 

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|xslt)$ /public/index.php
```

Any idea why its not loading?

Comment: try adding: RewriteBase /

Comment: I added RewriteBase / under the second line RewriteEngine but it still didnt load

Comment: What exact URL is failing? Logging %f in the access log would tell you where mod_Rewrite may have re-mapped it.

Comment: Hi, the URL is manager.diet

Comment: If you remove the htaccess completely, can you access the stylesheets/images?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there has been some cut-and-pasting: 'RewriteEngine on' should be there only once and the code from that point is causing you trouble.
The reasons for those lines are not clear without more info on the kind of site you run, so any advice from here is trial and error testing:

The last rule is commented out and looks like an effort to get the stylesheet and images (all js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|xml|xslt  files) correctly rewritten to the desired address. You can try to comment it out (get rid of the #).

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply, I have now updated the HTACCESS and the question.  I have taken out the comment in the last line but still no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by rewriting the whole file to the following

```
 DirectoryIndex /public/index.php

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteBase /public

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domainUrlNoHttp)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://(domainUrl)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```